# Hosted tool for software license usage?

Tags: licensing, analytics, tracking

I have a downloadable software product that I'd like to instrument with tracking so that I know how many people are using it.  I want data something like:

```
183 unique installations used on October 7, 2011
187 unique installations used on October 8, 2011
...
```

I do NOT need to know anything else about the users:  not the domain, not a license key, nothing.

This is a J2EE app with a web UI so I could use a Google Analytics-style tracking bug.  However, I've experimented with various permutations of GA page tracking and event tracking and haven't found a robust way to count the # installations used per day.

Is there a hosted service out there that offers this?  Some other approach to suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this with Google Analytics, though it's real hacky and I'd prefer a better solution.

Pick a web page that is always going to be hit on the installed system (like the front door).  Fire a Google Analytics event of the format:

- **Event Category:** "SystemID"
- **Event Name:** [Actual System ID]

In the Google Analytics UI, go to event tracking and create a search that returns all the events in the SystemID category.   The *pagination* will tell you how many unique system IDs there are. For example:  “Showing events 1 -15 of 15,000 in category SystemID”.

I couldn't find anything saying how many unique events Google supports, but Google says it supports collecting up to 50,000 unique URLs a day per profile.  Let’s assume that applies to events, too.  So you can set up a profile just for tracking this event, and it may last you up to 50,000 software installs.

Like I said, it's extremely hacky and I'd prefer a better solution, but it's gotta be one that's hosted and cheap to be better than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track unique installations per day, you need to create a unique key per installation per day and then you can track this. If that unique then contains the information as well to which date it belongs to, then the only thing you need to do it to log the keys somehow and then remove the duplicates.

The number of unique keys you will be able to identify per day are the unique installation used on that day.

It should be quite trivial to setup a webservice for that.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the problem.   I think you're suggesting roll everything from scratch -- set up a server and a database and write not only the web service but the reporting layer on top of it.  I was hoping to find a hosted service that did all this.  Failing that, an off the shelf freeware or low cost ware that did it...

Comment: well depending on your traffic you can just use `httpd` for servicing http, configure your own log format making use of you clever URL design with your id inside. `logrotate` will then put stuff by day and take care of the household. using `uniq` / `wc` on the log-files then does the counting job for you. that's rolling up your own but with existing components. I have no clue about your traffic however.